# Select Record where Maximum Count of character e.g 'A'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to Select a Record that has the Maximum Count of a character e.g 'A' and get this error "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.". What is causing this, and how can I correct it.Thanks!

```
select 
*

from GROUPS as G
inner join STUDENT_GROUP as SG
on sg.Group_ID = g.Groups_ID
inner join STUDENT as S
on s.Student_ID = sg.Student_ID
inner join STUDENT_MARKS as SM
on SM.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
inner join smark as m
on m.mark_id=sm.Mark_ID

where m.Mark_name = max(count('A'));
```

Comment: in witch column (field) do you want to focus character counting?

Comment: On the Mark_name column

Comment: Mr. Phronesis, I suggest you will make you question more precise. It would be excellent if you: a) create sqlfiddle for question, b) delete non-essential tables from request.  A little hints: a) GROUP BY means HAVING (not WHERE), b) m.Mark_name - i suppose it's a varchar, not an integer, c) "has Maximum count" - I suppose  you need calculation of counts, ORDER BY, TOP 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such function to count the times a particular character appears in a string, but you can use the length of original string and the lengh of the string after removing this particular character as this:

```
declare @foo nvarchar(max)
set @foo='abcabc'

select len(@foo)-len(replace(@foo,'a','')) as [Total of 'a']
```

In your case, using `TOP 1` will bring the first row in a particular order, and this order is count of character `A`

```
select top 1 *
from GROUPS as G
inner join STUDENT_GROUP as SG
on sg.Group_ID = g.Groups_ID
inner join STUDENT as S
on s.Student_ID = sg.Student_ID
inner join STUDENT_MARKS as SM
on SM.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
inner join smark as m
on m.mark_id=sm.Mark_ID
order by 
len(m.Mark_name)-len(replace(m.Mark_name,'A','')) DESC
```

As @jyao note, In case you need to get all records with the same max amount of character use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` as this:

```
select top 1 with ties *
...
```

Comment: Take for example we have  table Student_Marks that has columns Mark_ID (e.g1,2,3,4,5) and Mark_Name(E,D,C,B,A), and we have a table Student in relations with Student_Marks. How can we obtain the student that has the highest number of A's.

Comment: I vote up the answer, but I also need to mention the potential issue of this solution is that you can get one and only one record, but in reality you may have a few records with same # of 'A's, in such case, this solution is compromised.

Comment: @Mr.Phronesis, your comment and your question are not the same, or in another word, your question is not what you really want. It is better for you to prepare some sample data and give out your expected result, so people can help you with more concrete answer.

Comment: @Mr.Phronesis What you request now is another question. Try a new one and be more explicit and add data samples.ç